# KivyMD DatePicker save multiple dates

Tags: python, datepicker, kivy, kivymd

I want that you can add and choose multiple dates. I tried to send a number with the button click `button_nr` but I don't know how I can pass it to the `on_save` function, so that I can change the `self.ids.date_label(button_nr).text` . If somebody has a better idea how to save multiple dates I'm open for suggestions.
Thank you

```
def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
    date_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(value), "%Y-%m-%d")
    date_value_eu = date_value.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    self.ids.date_label1.text = str(date_value_eu)

def show_date_picker(self, button_nr):
    print(button_nr)
    date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
    date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save, on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
    date_dialog.open()
```

The kv file part

```
MDRaisedButton:
        on_release: root.show_date_picker(1)
```

Comment: I almost have an answer, I just want to ask, do you need to convert the same date that has been picked but to different date format, or do you need both, to convert that date to different formats and at the same time, update the text in the self.ids.date_label widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my code, I have designed this app in order to have a recycleview plus a search bar, the recycle list item in this example is moved into the pick date function and it changes the text of the list item widget (check the picture), here is the code by jbsidis (I am posting this after I commented your question):

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem

from kivy.properties import (
    StringProperty,
    BooleanProperty,
    ObjectProperty,
    NumericProperty,
    ListProperty,
    OptionProperty,
)
Window.size = (330, 660)


kv = '''
#:import MDTextField kivymd.uix.textfield.MDTextField
<MyTile@SmartTileWithLabel>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"

<S>:
    MDTextFieldRound:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}
        normal_color : [1,1,1,.1]
        color_active : [1,1,1,1]
        size_hint: .8, .07
        hint_text : 'Search a product...'
        icon_left : 'magnify'



<JBSIDIS>
    on_release: app.show_date_picker(root)
    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: "Photos/pro.jpg"

Screen:
    name: "pantalla1"
    MDToolbar:
        id: tb1
        title: "jbsidis"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        md_bg_color: (.1, .1, .5, 1)

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding: dp(20)
        FloatLayout:
            MDTextFieldRound:
                id: search_field
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .87}
                hint_text : 'jbsidis...'
                icon_left : 'magnify'
                normal_color : (100, 100, 50, .5)
                color_active : (255, 255, 255, 0)
                on_text: app.search(root.ids.rvvv9,self.text)

    BoxLayout:
        id: m5
        spacing: dp(10)
        #padding: dp(20)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .32}
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            id: s_res9
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
            orientation: "vertical"
        RecycleView:
            id: rvvv9
            key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
            key_size: 'height'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                padding: dp(10)
                spacing: dp(5)
                default_size: None, dp(75)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        id: success_screen_toolbar
        title: "jbsidis"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        right_action_items: [["progress-check", lambda: print(6)]]


    MDBottomAppBar:
        MDToolbar:
            id: success_screen_bottomappbar
            icon: "magnify"
            on_action_button: app.eq(root.ids.search_field,True)
            type: 'bottom'
            mode: 'center'
            #elevation: '8dp'
            left_action_items: [["calendar-text", lambda x: print(6)], ["account-group", lambda x: print(6)]]
            right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: app.eq(root.ids.search_field,True)], ["menu", lambda x: print(6)]]

'''
authors="jbsidis"
class JBSIDIS(OneLineIconListItem):
    datex=StringProperty()
    pass
class blanks1(BoxLayout):
    pass
class S(FloatLayout):
    pass

authors4="jbsidis"
books="""
Austen, Jane (72159) jbsidis
Du Bois, W. E. B. (William Edward Burghardt) (7364) jbsidis
Stowe, Harriet Beecher (7362) jbsidis
Vatsyayana (7343) jbsidis
Schopenhauer, Arthur (7317) jbsidis
Foote, Mary Hallock (7308) jbsidis
Bhide, Shivaram Parashuram (7256) jbsidis
Indrajit, Bhagavanlal (7256) jbsidis
"""
import time
import datetime
class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    def get_date(self, date):
        print(date)
        t=str(date).split("-")
        text="[b]"+str(t[-1])+"/"+str(t[1])+"/"+str(t[0])

        year=time.strftime("%Y")
        mes=time.strftime("%m")
        dia=time.strftime("%d")

        bx.text=text
        afecha=str(t[-1])+"/"+str(t[1])+"/"+str(t[0])
                            
        return date
    def show_date_picker(self,b):
        from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
        global bx
        bx=b

        yearx=time.strftime("%Y")
        mes=time.strftime("%m")
        dia=time.strftime("%d")

        current=time.strftime("%Y:%m:%d")

        min_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(current, '%Y:%m:%d').date()
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker(
            callback=self.get_date,
            min_date=min_date
            )
        date_dialog.open()

    def all_pdfs(self):
        return books.splitlines()
    def eq(self,a,b):
        a.focus=True
    def search(self,a,b):
        a.data=[]
        for x in self.all_pdfs():
            if b in str(x):
                a.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "JBSIDIS",
                    "markup": True,
                    "text": "[b][size=33]jbsidis: [/b][/size]"+str(x)
                }
                    )
        pass


Main().run()
```

This is one of many ways you can do things using kivy and kivymd, jbsidis, everything is possible with Python and Kivy, here is the image, greetings from El Salvador:

[image]

Comment: It's not really working for me. I want that you can open the calender with a button and save the date on a text. Then do the same thing again on the next button. The user should also be able to add more buttons.
So different buttons should be able to use the 'show_date_picker' function.
My problem is I don't know how to pass the button_nr to the 'on_save' function

Comment: Alright, I can surely help you doing it, you can edit your question and add the full code or at least the minimun part you need to have its functionality (as you have explained in your comment), so just share enough code and I will do it for you, otherwise, look at my answer given above and analyze how the Widget (the button_nr in your case) has been passed as an argument into the main class function and how I have assigned the value to the text given in the list, or share more code (in your code you need to give us more about the kv lang part. Or just add the id "button_nr" to the widget

Comment: Thank you. I could solve it.
Do you know if there is a way to select multiple dates in the calender, not a range

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's a great question, I know the lastest KivyMD has the function to select a range of dates but it does not have the option to select multiple dates and save them (may be in a list), but it is actually something possible, I will be modifying the MDDatePicker and maybe I will be adding an additional functionality to be able to select several dates instead of just a range of dates, it will take time but it is possible.